# CreateView doesn't save object , throws 'this field is required ' error

Tags: django, django-views, create-view

models.py is :

```py
class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

views.py is:

```py
class TaskCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Todo
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

create.html is:

```html
<body>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">go back</a>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Whenever I submit data from create.html form it doesn't save it to the database and throws this field is required on 'user' field. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to exclude the `user` field, since it is determined by the logged in user, so:

```
from django.conf import settings


class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False
    )
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

Then we inject the logged in user in the instance of the form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class TaskCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Todo
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `TaskCreateView`, instead of <s>`TaskCreate`</s>.